# Devise install from existing model/database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I am wondering how can i add devise to an existing database with a different user. Here I already have a customer model define and I want to change to allow devise to work on it.

I have created a new migration and inserted the code has follow

```
class AddDeviseToCustomer < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :customers do |t|
      #t.database_authenticatable
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => '', :limit => 128
      t.confirmable
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable
      t.token_authenticatable
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

According to this it should work. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-change-an-already-existing-table-to-add-devise-required-columns. But when running rake db:migrate i get the following

```
undefined method `confirmable' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Table:0x9286a28>
```

I have run the following line

```
rails g devise:install
```

Any reason devise won't recognize it, do i need to do something to say customer is a devise??
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you add "devise" gem to your Gemfile and then run "bundle install"? just a confirmation :)

Comment: yes i did, but i see there is no helper involved. should i worry about these?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like that documentation is outdated.

Try using devise generator, it will create same migration, with correct parameters, it's ok if its an existing model:

```
rails g devise customer
```

it should create `AddDeviseToCustomers` migration

with something similar to this:

```
class AddDeviseToCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration
def self.up
change_table(:customers) do |t|
  ## Database authenticatable
  t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  ## Trackable
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

  ## Confirmable
  t.string   :confirmation_token
  t.datetime :confirmed_at
  t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # t.datetime :locked_at

  ## Token authenticatable
  # t.string :authentication_token


  # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
  # t.timestamps
end

def self.down
# By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
# model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
end
end
```

note that there is no more `t.confirmable`

Comment: Woudl it erase my current user?

Comment: No. Try it yourself in a dummy project :) Also, you can access [devise 2.0 document here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style)

Comment: Thanks it works now i need to learn devise and use it properly

Comment: I'm glad it did help. Be sure you are reading devise 2.0 docs. Good luck.

Comment: @AlperKarapınar What if my non devise model already has email column. What would you recommend in that case?

Comment: Yes Rahul, it should just work. But do not forget to remove email field from the generated migration file.

Comment: @AlperKarapınar Instead of removing it why not change it? like this


 ```t.change :email, :string,     null: false, default: "" ```