# Ruby on Rails - Devise Confirmable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, has-and-belongs-to-many, devise-confirmable

Im a RoR rookie and am using rails 3.2.3.

I've been using devise and so far it has been great, however, I've run into a problem.

I have a `User` table with devise and a HABTM association with a Role table. I have the join table created and everything is fine. When I create a user and choose it's role, it creates the data in the join table correctly.

However, I activated devises' `confirmable` option and things started to go wrong.
When I create a new user, **it no longer inserts the record in the join table as it should.**

I mean, all I have literary done was add `, :confirmable` in front of the other devise options such as `:database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable` and `:validatable`.

When I activated `:confirmable` I wrote this migration (which I saw on stack overflow also):

```
class AddConfirmableToDeviseV < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
    change_table(:users) do |t| 
      t.confirmable 
    end
    add_index  :users, :confirmation_token, :unique => true 
  end
end
```

It sends the email with the link to confirm, nothing wrong with that, but when I click it, the app breaks as that user does not have a role assigned to it, and that is a must.

And as I said, all I did was add `:confirmable`. **If I comment it out like this `#,:confirmable`** in my User model, **the role and user data gets inserted in the join table correctly.**

What's going on? Any tips?

Thanks in advance,

Regards

## Update

@Kyle C

I'm creating the user with the regular actions:

View:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
</div>
(...)

<% for role in Role.find(:all) %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", role.id, @user.roles.include?(role) %>
  <%= role.name %>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

Then in my controller:

```
def create

@user = User.new(params[:user])    

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
  (...)
```

**Without `:confirmable`**, this is enough to enter the data in the join table.

On top of this, I have this in my app controller:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)

if current_user.roles.first.id == 1
  admin_dashboard_path
elsif current_user.roles.first.id == 2
  manage_path
end

end
```

If i take this out, the user gets logged in when he clicks the confirmation email, **however**, the middle join table is still doesn't get the association.

I've browsed the documentation (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb)
but I'm still a rookie and I also didn't find anything that would override my app's initial behaviour.

Is there a way to force the input of the records in my join table after I create the user?

I've tried this:

```
def create

@user = User.new(params[:user])
@role = Role.find(params[:user][:role_ids])

if @user.save
@user.role << @role
@user.save
```

AND (wrong thing to do but still without success)

```
(...)
if @user.save
query = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.prepare("INSERT INTO roles_users (role_id, user_id) VALUES (?,?);")
query.execute(@role.id, @user.id)
query.close
```

This is really frustrating, anyone else came up with this issue when activating `:confirmable` with a HABTM?

Thanks for all your help

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954270/devise-install-from-existing-model-database) exactly same problem. check devise 2.0 docs.

Comment: I have done this (except for :unconfirmed_email) but the Role in my join table (users_role) is still not being created. What could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

t.confirmable is no longer supported please use this migration

```
   ## Confirmable
  # t.string   :confirmation_token
  # t.datetime :confirmed_at
  # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  # t.string   :unconfirmed_email
```

Comment: I have done this (except for :unconfirmed_email) but the Role in my join table (users_role) is still not being created. What could it be?

Comment: How are you adding the role to the user? Is it in an after_create callback? Please post the code

Comment: Try '@user.roles << @role', it is a HMABTM association so roles should be plural and you cannot append something unless it is a has many association.

Comment: Thanks Kyle C, it actually worked, it is indeed a HABMT, but since it was just only one role to one user, I used `@user.role << @role`, and that was exactly what was wrong. Your solution worked, thank you very much and best regards.