# Trying to $ rake db:migrate but get this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the error I get in the Terminal. What is wrong?

```
DeviseCreateUsers: migrating
-- create_table(:users) rake aborted! An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists: CREATE TABLE 
  "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "email"
  varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "encrypted_password" varchar(255) 
  DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "reset_password_token" varchar(255), 
  "reset_password_sent_at" datetime, "remember_created_at" datetime, 
  "sign_in_count" integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, "current_sign_in_at" 
  datetime, "last_sign_in_at" datetime, "current_sign_in_ip"
  varchar(255), "last_sign_in_ip" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime,
  "updated_at" datetime) 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:331:in `block in execute'
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:435:in `block in log'
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in > `instrument' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:430:in `log'
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:331:in `execute'
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:190:in `create_table'
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:625:in `block in method_missing' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:597:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:597:in `say_with_time'
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:617:in `method_missing' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/Desktop/pinteresting/db/migrate/20140205151417_devise_create_users.rb:3:in `change'
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:571:in `exec_migration' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in migrate' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:554:in `block in migrate' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in `migrate' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:709:in `migrate'
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in `ddl_transaction' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:958:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:920:in `block in migrate' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in `each' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in `migrate' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `up' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate' 
/Users/danieljuzovitskij/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See > full trace by running task with --trace)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Looks like the table is already created. check file `db/scheme.rb` and see if the User table is there

Comment: It seems you already have `users` table. Drop it and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears like your migrations are out of sync with you database.  If this is a dev environment I'd recommend doing the following rake tasks.

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

> SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists:

That error means that your "users" table has already been created. Either drop the table or make sure that a later migration is not trying to recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your failed migration is called `DeviseCreateUsers`. I'd recommend checking [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954270/devise-install-from-existing-model-database) Which is how you add Devise to an already created User model.

I'd recommend rolling back your last changes (like the creation of your failing migration) and doing that. Just for consistency:

```
rails g devise user
```

Will add the migrations necessary and check if the table is already created or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
force: :true

```
create_table :users, force: true do |t|
 // your contents
end
```

It will drop existing table and create new one.